# SQL - Getting a single branch of a hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression, tree-traversal

I have the following table "x" of hierarchical attributes:

```
+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| row       | value  | displayvalue | parentrow | parentvalue |
+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| HIE1      | VALUE3 | value 3      | NULL      | NULL        |
| HIE2      | VALUE1 | value 11     | HIE1      | VALUE1      |
| HIE2      | VALUE1 | value 21     | HIE1      | VALUE2      |
| HIE2      | VALUE1 | value 31     | HIE1      | VALUE3      |
| HIE3      | VALUE1 | value 111    | HIE2      | VALUE1      |
| HIE3      | VALUE1 | value 311    | HIE2      | VALUE1      |
| HIE3      | VALUE1 | value 221    | HIE2      | VALUE2      |
+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
```

This is just an example - the hierarchy might be bigger or smaller, and the row codes do not have to be numerical. How do I go about extracting the only correct branch in this table? i.e.:

```
+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| row       | value  | displayvalue | parentrow | parentvalue |
+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| HIE1      | VALUE3 | value 3      | NULL      | NULL        |
| HIE2      | VALUE1 | value 31     | HIE1      | VALUE3      |
| HIE3      | VALUE1 | value 311    | HIE2      | VALUE1      |
+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
```

This will require recursion, and I've tried:

```
With Attrs AS (
    SELECT "row",
           "value",
           "displayvalue",
           "parentrow",
           "parentvalue",
     FROM x

    UNION ALL

    SELECT child."row",
           child."value",
           child."displayvalue",
           child."parentrow",
           child."parentvalue",
     FROM x child
     JOIN Attrs ON child."parentrow" = Attrs."row" AND child."parentvalue" = Attrs."value"
     WHERE Attrs."parentrow" IS NOT NULL

  )
  SELECT "row", "value", "displayvalue", "parentrow", "parentvalue"
  FROM Attrs;
```

But this seems to expand the result pool rather than narrowing it down. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Forgot to add the sequence columns in the table. These are the extra entries:

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+
| row       | seqno  | parentseq |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
| HIE1      | 3      | NULL      |
| HIE2      | 10     | 1         |
| HIE2      | 13     | 2         |
| HIE2      | 11     | 3         |
| HIE3      | 15     | 10        |
| HIE3      | 16     | 11        |
| HIE3      | 17     | 12        |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

The desired rows would have:

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+
| row       | seqno  | parentseq |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
| HIE1      | 3      | NULL      |
| HIE2      | 11     | 3         |
| HIE3      | 16     | 11        |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: What determines if a branch is correct? Is it the display name?

Comment: So there are `parentrow`/`parentvalue` combinations for which does not exist a `row`/`value` combination, so these must be ignored? But what makes `value 311` part of the correct branch and `` not? Both have the same `parentrow`/`parentvalue` combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
;WITH Attrs AS (
   -- Anchor query: Get the root records
   SELECT row, value, displayvalue, parentrow, parentvalue
   FROM x
   WHERE parentrow IS NULL

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive query: Get the records of the next level
   SELECT child.row, child.value, child.displayvalue, child.parentrow, child.parentvalue
   FROM x AS child
   INNER JOIN Attrs AS parent 
      ON child.parentrow = parent.row AND child.parentvalue = parent.value
)
SELECT row, value, displayvalue, parentrow, parentvalue
FROM Attrs
```

The first subquery of the recursive `CTE`, also called *anchor* query, gets the root records of the hierarchy. Hence, you have to place `parentrow IS NULL` on this subquery.

The second subquery joins the table with the results from the previous recursion to get the records of the next level in the tree hierarchy. There is no need to use `parentrow IS NULL` in this subquery as the records emanating from the first execution of the recursion are *already* the root node records.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ffe8ad/1)

**Edit:** Adding the sequence numbers to the query we get:

```
;WITH Attrs AS (
   -- Anchor query: Get the root records
   SELECT row, seqno, value, displayvalue, 
          parentrow, parentvalue, parentseq
   FROM x
   WHERE parentrow IS NULL

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive query: Get the records of the next level
   SELECT child.row, child.seqno, child.value, child.displayvalue, 
          child.parentrow, child.parentvalue, child.parentseq
   FROM x AS child
   INNER JOIN Attrs AS parent 
      ON child.parentrow = parent.row AND 
         child.parentvalue = parent.value AND 
         child.parentseq = parent.seqno
)
SELECT row, value, displayvalue, parentrow, parentvalue
FROM Attrs
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! It's close, but I'm getting an extra HIE3 entry in your demo. Possibly because both those entries have their parent value as VALUE1.

Comment: @user2850751 Why should record `HIE3, VALUE1, value 111, HIE2, VALUE1` be excluded from the results? It seems like a legitimate leaf record.

Comment: Good point. I think I forgot to mention that there was a sequence number there.

Comment: @user2850751 There ... where ?

Comment: Edited. If I add the sequence numbers comparison to your code, it works!

Comment: @user2850751 I'm glad you got it to work finally! Edited my answer accordingly.